# compile with swi-prolog without including interactive prolog environment into binary

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am learning prolog, and I use swi-prolog as a compiler/interpreter. I have this hello world file:

```
:- initialization(main).
main :- format('Hello, world').
```

but when I try to compile it with `swipl -o hello.exe -c hello.pro` and run the binary `hello.exe`, it runs the goal first (main) but then returns me to the swi-prolog interactive environment. How do I just compile it so it's a functioning program without the prolog environment?
I also tried adding `halt` at the end of main, but that doesn't compile at all. When I try that, the compiler prints "Hello, world" and then just stops compiling.

Comment: For clarity, are you saying you put `halt` after `main` inside the initialization directive?  Or that you added `halt` as the tail call in defining `main/0`?

Comment: @hardmath as a tail call in defining `main/0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

- remove the `:-initialization` directive
- compile with: `swipl.exe -nodebug -g true -O -q --toplevel=main --stand_alone=true -o hello.exe -c hello.pro`

That should do the trick