# Running a single non-interactive swi-prolog query

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
edge(1,2).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,4).

connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), connected(Z,Y).

result :- connected(1,4).
main :- format('%d', result).
```

But when I try to compile and run, I get inside an infinite loop:

```
$ swipl -nodebug -g true -O -q --toplevel=main --stand_alone=true -o main -c main.pl
$ ./main
ERROR: Format error: too many arguments
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [4] format('%d',result)
%d
# ... the above 3 ERRORs keep running infinitely ...
```

---

Related (an epsilon-more complicated than): [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480946/compile-with-swi-prolog-without-including-interactive-prolog-environment-into-bi)

Comment: There are errors in your code, in the format/2 call. results only evaluates to true (as in this case) or false

Comment: @damianodamiano you mean there is no automatic conversion from boolean to integer? is that the case here? can I do an explicit cast somehow? thanks !

Comment: Prolog is completely different from other imperative languages. There are no return values from predicates.

Comment: How can I print the result of `connected(1,4)` to stdout?

Comment: Your question doesn't have any questions in it. That isn't how format works/2, it needs a list as its second parameter, or how the format strings work, they aren't C style they need `~w` and similar, and predicates don't have results - they hold or don't hold. You could do `main :- (connected(1,4) -> write('yes') ; write('no')).` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler thanks ! it worked. I have absolutely no experience in Prolog, but it seems that some of your remarks *can* be caught during compile time? the `swipl` command issues no warnings / errors, and only during runtime everything explodes.

Comment: If you are going to expand that program to many more nodes, you should add `:- tabled connected/2.` It will memoize the connections and greatly improve performance.